# Dynamic query building yields no results and crashes process

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

I am trying to run a SQL query within a PL/SQL script that takes dynamic parameters and should return a specific result. For that I tried the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` command. Unfortunately it crashes always my variable is a varchar. If it is a number instead it runs perfetcly.

Here is my tried code:

```
plsql_request := 'SELECT :x FROM TEST_TABLE WHERE ID = :y';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE plsql_request INTO plsql_result USING variable_1, '2837123 | hsiae';
```

While testing it crashes always in this constelation.
Second approch:

```
plsql_request := 'SELECT ' || variable_1 || ' FROM TEST_TABLE WHERE ID = ''' || variable_2 || '''';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE plsql_request ;
```

I do not get any results at all, hence I think the query-building using dynamic variables in combination with varchars fails.

Any help apreciated,
Filip.

Comment: What do you mean by "it crashes"? What error do you get? (Presumably one that is fixed by PaulW's combined approach? The second query will get no result because that one doesn't have an `INTO` clause any more.

Comment: @AlexPoole I develope with Oracle Apex. I use this PL/SQL script in a process. WHen it comes to the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE line the whole program crashes.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use a bind variable for an object literal like a column name, table name, etc..  so you must use the second method with || variable_1 || to splice in your dynamic column name. However, you should use real bind variables :y, USING, etc.. for your predicate value in order to not generate an excessive number of child cursors.

So, :

```
plsql_request := 'SELECT '||variable_1||' FROM TEST_TABLE WHERE ID = :y';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE plsql_request INTO plsql_result USING '2837123 | hsiae';
```